# Add angular.js in HTML file

Tags: html, angularjs, intellij-idea, bower

I am new at web development and working on one project where i have to use bower tool for front end development.I have created a project in intellij and installed bower and grunt on local project with angular js and jquery.i have created a file called index.html and its working fine when i write HTML but now i want to code in angular js. So i have added the script tag which is shown below in html file  but it doesnt work. I know its a basic thing but i am not able to get it. I tried many things. Thank you in advance.

Comment: sorry the tag is <script src="bower_components/angularjs/angular.js></script>

Comment: did you make it work?

Comment: thanks its working without grunt serve . I have simply added the path of angular js in my html file and it works but it doesn't show suggestion and now i am trying to do some jquery but it not working.

Comment: @Ethaan can u will be more specific about the manually installation because i dont get it. I have read many documents and it says that we have to inject all the dependencies to work them in html file but i dont know how to do that

Comment: i am using intellij idea

Comment: ya i know its an ide. So we can use it for any programming languages.

Comment: forget my comment, first  Make sure the NodeJS and AngularJS plugins are installed enabled.

Comment: if you don't have it, install from [here](http://plugins.jetbrains.com)

Answer (score 1):

Ok just to make sure.

**first**

Check into the  `bower_components` directory if the `Angular` folder is there.

If angular folder is there, like on the image.
[image]

if the file its not there run `bower install angular` or `sudo bower install angular`

**second**

> You could manually add the Angular Sortable 
>   script files yourself but Yeoman will automate this for you!

now run `grunt serve` just to check if angular script tag is there.

you should get this on console.

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

**Third**

If this is ok, you could start getting into this tutorials to start using Angular.

[W3 School Angular tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/)

[thinkster.io Tutorial](https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/)

[From angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_01)

Comment: This answer is for simple HTML file but i am using bower tool . So we have to install angular js using the terminal with the following command called bower installed angular js and it installed but now i want to use it inside bower project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

include the Angular Javascript file via script tag.
http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/introduction/including-the-angular-library-code-in-an-html-page.html
 check this link for detail